# rewrite get parameter with custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

I am trying now for a couple days to solve the following Problem:

I have a custom post type called `gallery`. I need the URL

```
http://example.com/gallery/FOOBAR
```

to be parsed like

```
http://example.com/gallery/?param=FOOBAR
```

The Permalink Setting for custom post type is:

```
/gallery/%postname%/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/
```

I think I have tried about every code snipped that I could find to solve this problem but nothing seems to work.
If I flush all rewrites, none of my links work anymore (404)

Is is even possible?

Answer (score 3):

I think it should work. First you need to register your rewrite rule and the parameter:

```
function my_init() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'gallery/(.+?)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=gallery&param=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
    add_rewrite_tag('%param%','([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

Then you can read the parameter value from the query:

```
$param = get_query_var('param');
```

Don't forget to flush the rewrites. (just view the rewrite settings page to flush the rules)